# Java split string at Uppercase and convert all to lowercase

Tags: java, android, string, format

I want to be able to split a string right at the uppercase letter then convert them all to lowercase. I was able to split the uppercase letter using:

```
    public String getString() {
    return string.replaceAll(
              String.format("%s|%s|%s",
                 "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])",
                 "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])",
                 "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"
              ),
              " "
           );
        }
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to convert it all to lowercase. What is the best way to do that? Do I set that in another String variable and use toLowerCase?

EDIT: For Clarification, showing input and output.

Input: `smallCat`

Output: `small Cat`

The desired output is: `small cat`

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Can you show some sample input and required outputs?

Comment: edited for clarification.

Comment: why dont you use string.toLowerCase()?

Comment: @JavaKB  Op asking   `Do I set that in another String variable and use toLowerCase?`, question is the replace all functions result should be assigned to another string or direct `toLowerCase`  works or not :)

Comment: Yeah SURESH ATTA's solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for another string

simply  use `toLowerCase()`

```
 public   String getString() {
            return string.replaceAll(
                      String.format("%s|%s|%s",
                         "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])",
                         "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])",
                         "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"
                      ),
                      " "
                   ).toLowerCase();
                }
```

**Test:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

        System.out.println(getString());
    }

     public static String getString() {
            return "sdsDsfsWerGDLKSAsdfsdfSAA".replaceAll(
                      String.format("%s|%s|%s",
                         "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])",
                         "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])",
                         "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"
                      ),
                      " "
                   ).toLowerCase();
                }
```

output:

```
sds d sfs w er gdlksa sdfsdf saa
```

Comment: damn you genius, you can have my babies